# Unable to install php mcrypt and intl Extension

Tags: php, mcrypt, intl

my fellow developers, i have just barely started to install magento for me to use it and see how it behaves,
i downloaded the zip file from [here](https://magento.com/tech-resources/download) extracted it, and tried to run it in localhost of my MAC OS X, but it is showing me 2 missing extensions extension check

1. PHP Extension mcrypt
2. PHP Extension intl.

now i have tried to install mcrypt with

```
brew install mcrypt
```

it shows me the path where it is installed which is `/usr/local/Cellar/mcrypt/2.6.8`and that is fine, i cannot find mcrypt.so file init which lots of online totorials have stated that should be there and to put that file reference in php.ini file, but i cannot find the file in there,

and `brew install intl`
or `brew install php70-intl`

is not even working to begin with, it shows me these 4 errors when i run this.

```
Error: No available formula with the name "intl" 
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
Error: No formulae found in taps.


Error: No available formula with the name "php70-intl" 
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

Any ideas what i might me doing wrong, or am i missing something,
any help is appritiated, thankyou
BTW my php version is 7.1.16

Comment: Which version of PHP? Mcrypt, at least, has been removed from 7.2 (so yeah, Magento currently doesn't support PHP 7.2).

Comment: my version of php is 7.1.16

Comment: They moved the repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They moved the repo.

You need to do the following. "php@7.1" already contains mcrypt/intl.

"brew install php@7.1"

Comment: my current php installed version is 7.1.16, is it different than this php@7.1?

Comment: Might be it depends how you installed it. Via "brew install php@7.1" you get mcrypt and intl.

Comment: it works thankyou, pre installed version is 7.1.16, but installing with brew install php@7.1 gives 7.1.18, which comes with the intl and mcrypt pre installed,
i dont understand i have tried with 7.0.30 as well, it also comes with them installed, why is that the version in between doesn't come with it :p